# Creating a MySQL table upon user registration

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website which will collect and store information for users.

I need to create a table specific to each individual user on registration to store the information they are searching for using the website. The table created will be named after the newly registered user's username.

Then when the user is logged in and runs the search, the data collected will be stored in a database using a MySQL insert query where the table name is a variable containing the logged-in user's username which will also be the table name.

I am an amateur developer and have searched everywhere to try and find a solution but I cannot seem to find anything evenly remotely similar to my problem.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Per-user tables are a pretty major design no-no. Why can't you have a SINGLE table and just have one RECORD per user?

Comment: Not that you asked, but I don't find it to be a good idea to create a table for a user. Why not just have one huge table with the user's name or identifier?

Comment: "I need to create a table specific to each individual user" **NO. STOP.** Rethink what you're doing.

Comment: The website is collecting contact information from other websites that the user wants to collect the contact information from. The reason I was wanting to create a table per user is so the user can view all the contact information they individually have collected. I know this may not be good practice but I do not plan on having a high volume of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating tables on the fly is more trouble than it's worth and very much swimming against the tide with any SQL database.

The reason you haven't found any docs about the approach you mention is because this problem is generally (almost without exception) solved best by having all the data in one or more tables, and including a column to specify which entity (user) the row is associated with. In your case, this might be an email address, or a username, or just a sequential number.

E.g.

```
 | user_id | email   | first_name   | last_name   | fave_color   |
 -         -         -              -             -              -
 |       1 | "a@b.c" | "anton"      | "aardvark"  | "red"        |
 |       2 | "b@c.d" | "miles"      | "o'brien"   | "infrared"   |
 |     ... |         |              |             |              |
```

Comment: This seems much more logical than my proposed method. So i would insert the users unique identifier into the table on the same row as the search results, then when the user wants to see their collected data I would use the users unique identifier as the variable in the MySQL select query.

Comment: I wouldn't use user_email as the user's primary key. If a user changes their email address you'll either lose data (bad) and lose referential integrity (bad), or have to do a massive update over all of their records (bad). To paraphrase Ignacio, "surrogate keys 4evar!"

Comment: updated to show a more realistic example (using a primary key)

Answer (score 0):

First take name from user like:

```
$fullname="$fname"."_"."$lname";
```

Then, write a query like this to create a table of that name

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE $fullname(ALL THE COLLUMNS YOU WANT TO CREATE)";
$result1=mysql_query($sql, $db_link);
```

this query is from my project. Works fine in wampserver.

Comment: I'm sure that all the `John Smith` people of the world will thank you when their private data gets co-mingled with all the other john smiths. Your project will also explode if `Miles O'Brien` signs up. So, -1 for you.